# Django: ValueError when saving an instance to a ForeignKey Field

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to save an instance of a model but get a ValueError.

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "<DataPointModel: DataPointModel object>": 
"Bike.data_point" must be a "DataPointModel" instance.
```

The model has a very simple field:

```
data_point = models.ForeignKey(DataPointModel, null=True, blank=True)
```

And the method is as well.

```
data_point = DataPointModel.objects.filter(
    object_id=bike.reference_model.id,
).last()
watch.data_point = data_point
watch.save()
```

Why is this not saving?

Comment: If it work you can appreciate by up voting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you update or create anything in the table contains foreign Key you need to pass the object of primary key instead of passing real value.So you have to call the `get` query to primary key value table then pass that obj to foreign key column as a value.

Example :-

Suppose I have two model as follows:-

```
class model1(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(primary_key=True,,max_length=2000)
    className=models.CharField(max_length=2000,null=True)

class model2(models.Model):
    name=models.ForeignKey(model1)
    teacher=models.CharField(max_length=2000,null=True)

views.py:-

jimmy = model2.objects.get(name="Jimmy")
obj = model1.objects.get(name='Piyush')
model2.objects.filter(id=jimmy.id).update(teacher=obj)
```

Comment: Thanks Piyush for the answer. In your example, I'm trying to update model2.teacher . I don't want to update al of the model2 models. I believe that is what your example does?

Comment: " don't want to update al of the model2 models", what do you mean?

Comment: model2.objects.filter(name=obj).update(teacher='Emile') would query for all model2's with obj. I have a specific instance I want to update, in this example 'watch'

Comment: I don't think so actually `model2.objects.filter(name=obj)` part just check the reference and filter and then `.update()` will update the whatever matching fields, this is what my understanding is correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Ohh thanks , can you just modify it then so that I will get to know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135018/discussion-between-emile-and-piyush-s-wanare).

Comment: @Emile What about for Post.objects.all() with foreign key.