# Django Can't save record with ForeinKey

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-3.6

I am familiar with the Django and I am using Django framework(2.2.2) in one of my website, But I am getting one weird issue for saving record with the foreign key:

I have following two models

```
class quick_note(models.Model):
   note_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   meeting_date = models.DateField(max_length=55)
   title = models.TextField(blank = True,null=True)
   headline = models.TextField(blank = True,null=True)

class quick_note_details(models.Model):
   meeting_id = models.ForeignKey(quick_note,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
   summary = models.TextField(default='',null=True)
```

Following is the code I have used for saving:

```
quick_note_details_data = quick_note_details(summary = summary_data,meeting_id = 1)
quick_note_details_data.save()
```

Using this I am getting following error:

*ValueError: Cannot assign "2": "quick_note_details.meeting_id" must be a "quick_note" instance.*

Then, I have tried the following approach suggested in the following question,

[Django: ValueError when saving an instance to a ForeignKey Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42081593/django-valueerror-when-saving-an-instance-to-a-foreignkey-field)

```
quick_note_obj  = quick_note.objects.get(note_id = note_id)     
quick_note_details_data = quick_note_details(summary = summary_data,meeting_id = quick_note_obj)
    quick_note_details_data.save()
```

Using this I am getting following error:

*django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "meeting_id_id" of relation "website_quick_note_details" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "website_quick_note_details" ("meeting_id_id", "...*

I don't have a column like **meeting_id_id** in the model anywhere, then why I am getting this error?

I have been searching for this long time, but didn't get any solution,

Hope I will get help here.

Answer (score 0):

change meeting_id to meeting_id_id , try following 
`quick_note_details_data = quick_note_details(summary = summary_data,meeting_id_id = 1)`

Answer (score 0):

So, I had got my answer days back, so decided to answer so this will help people like me,

Basically, Django appends a suffix to the foreign_key columns,

e.g if your columns name is note ,Django will assume this as note_id,

So,To avoid this I had done only the following:

```
note_id = models.ForeignKey(quick_note,on_delete = models.CASCADE,db_column='note_id')
```

By using *db_column* property, now the foreign key will refer as note_id,

This solves my issue.